# Transfer capacity between two partitions

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have created two partitions:

- System 850GB
- Data 150GB

what I actually want is:

- System 200GB
- Data 800GB

...however, disk utility doesn't let me either merge these two partitions or transfer the size between them. All it lets me do is create more partitions and it doesn't allow merging partitions from System with partitions from Data.

Clicking on minus here does nothing:

[image]

Comment: Ya... The new disk utility is messed up in El Captain. You cans really resize anything without creating weird new partitions and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of task I would always have given to [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com/iPartition/), however, it doesn't like CoreStorage drives [File Vault & Fusion Drives both use this format] & also it will break Drobos.

You also need the current beta before it will support El Capitan.

With all those caveats it makes it harder to recommend these days.